# Google Sheets: Adding commas to each username but username has no consistent format

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with 20+ users working on it. There is a list of usernames and my goal is to concatenate text to hyperlink the username in markdown format. This is so that the username can be clickable in our internal dashboard. Currently I have a formula that converts the username into hyperlink in markdown. The issue is that the formula does not work correctly when there is no comma separating the username.

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",map(index(trim(split(substitute(Σ,"@",),","))),lambda(Λ,"["&Λ&"](https://example.com/u/"&Λ&")"))))))
```

[Example Google Sheet with multiple examples.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1AFBww8BphnWxtlhlEth_rYHOV5mia76f6DEvzH88daI/edit#gid=0)

| username | attempt | desired result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jacklee@ | [jacklee](https://example.com/u/jacklee) | [jacklee](https://example.com/u/jacklee) |
| @bradmiller mikejones@ | [bradmillermikejones](https://example.com/u/bradmillermikejones) | [bradmiller](https://example.com/u/bradmiller), [mikejones](https://example.com/u/mikejones) |

Comment: Your formula only splits using comma. Use CHAR(10) to split the line breaks. Make a list of possible characters to avoid surprises. It will also help to trim each split values to remove  trailing white spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this small tweak from your existing formula.

I added a `REGEXREPLACE` in `SPLIT` function to add a delimiter for `commas`,`whitespaces` and `newline`

### Formula:

```
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",map(index(trim(split(REGEXREPLACE(substitute(Σ,"@",), "[,\s\n]", "~"), "~"))),lambda(Λ,"["&Λ&"](https://example.com/u/"&Λ&")"))))))
```

### Output:

[image]

### Reference:

[REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en)

Comment: Hi @George, is there a way if the formula finds "TBD", it will not hyperlink TBD and just leave it as it? My attempt but not working: `=map(A2:A,IF(A2="TBD","TBD",lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",map(index(trim(split(REGEXREPLACE(substitute(Σ,"@",), "[,\s\n]", "~"), "~"))),lambda(Λ,"["&Λ&"](https://example.com/u/"&Λ&")")))))))`

Comment: Got it working with trial and error :D `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="TBD", "TBD", map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,join(", ",map(index(trim(split(REGEXREPLACE(substitute(Σ,"@",), "[,\s\n]", "~"), "~"))),lambda(Λ,"["&Λ&"](https://example.com/u/"&Λ&")"))))))))`

Answer (score 1):

*The above formula has **split()** with one delimiter assigned as such `","`*

*Just change that part of the formula to `", "&char(10)` (which assigns additional delimiters now) and the formula should work as you intended*

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
=MAP(A2:A7,LAMBDA(user,JOIN(CHAR(10),ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(user,"@, "&CHAR(10)),".+","[$0](https://example.com/u/$0)")))))
```